# How to load a model saved as RDS file from Python and make predictions?

Tags: python, r, rpy2

I have a machine learning model saved in *.rds format. I want to open this model in Python in order to make predictions. To do so, I installed `rpy2`. This is my Jupyter Notebook code:

```
!pip install rpy2

import json
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import rpy2.robjects as robjects
from rpy2.robjects import numpy2ri
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr

r = robjects.r
numpy2ri.activate()

model_rds_path = "model.rds"
model = r.readRDS(model_rds_path)

raw_data = '{"data":[[79],[63]]}'
data = json.loads(raw_data)["data"]

if type(data) is not np.ndarray:
    data = np.array(data)

result = r.predict(model, data, probability=False)
result
```

I get the following error at the line `r.predict(…)`:

```
RRuntimeError: Error in model.frame.default(Terms, newdata, na.action = na.action, xlev = object$xlevels) : 
  'data' must be a data.frame, not a matrix or an array
Calls: <Anonymous> -> predict.lm -> model.frame -> model.frame.default
```

The training script in R looks as follows:

```
library(caret)

# Reading `data` from CSV file
x <- data$height
y <- data$weight

model <- lm(y~x)

# Test predictions
df_test_heights <- data.frame(x = as.numeric(c(115,20)))
result <- predict(model,df_test_heights)
print(result)
```

I am so much confused… Spent whole day trying to solve this issue!! Does anybody know how to fix it??? I would also appreciate if somebody knows an alternative way (alternative to `rpy2`) to open RDS files from Python.

Thanks!!!

Comment: I thhink the issue is that the `predict` expects the `newdata` as a `data.frame` .  Here, you are passing a python array

Comment: @akrun: Ok, thanks. Could you suggest how to pass `data` as `data.frame` from python?

Comment: Just create a data.frame as `pd.DataFrame` and assign it to `R` env ( I can't test a non-reproducible example

Comment: @akrun: I created `pd.DataFrame` from `numpy`, but what do you mean by "assign it to R"? If I pass `data` as `pd.DataFrame` to `r.predict(…)`, then the code fails again.

Comment: You are using `r.predict` and the model is read with `r.readRDS`.  So iff both of these are R function/objects, the newdata should be also an R datafrrame

Comment: I am using `mac` and have some difficultites in installing `rpy2`.  I posted a solution with `pyper`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The R function `predict()` will expect an R data frame for `data`. However, what you have as this point is a numpy array.

```
data = json.loads(raw_data)["data"]

if type(data) is not np.ndarray:
    data = np.array(data)
```

In Python, `pandas`'s `DataFrame` objects are a closer conceptual equivalent to R data frames. This section of the rpy2 documentation might help you:

https://rpy2.github.io/doc/v3.2.x/html/pandas.html

Answer (score 2):

Here is an option with `pyper`

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pyper import *
import json
r=R(use_pandas=True)
model_rds_path = "model.rds"
r.assign("rmodel", model_rds_path)


raw_data = '{"data":[[79],[63]]}'
data = json.loads(raw_data)["data"]

if type(data) is not np.ndarray:
    data = dat = pd.DataFrame( np.array(data), columns = ['x'])


r.assign("rdata", data)
# rdata
expr  = 'model <- readRDS(rmodel); result <- predict(model, rdata, probability=False)'
r(expr)
res= r.get('result')
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about `pyper`. I will consider it for my experiments.